# Netlogo random patches setup without them touching at all

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to set up random patches that have no corners touching at all, and the color of those patches are different colors of green (to visually represent each patch having a random quality value in my model). My conceptual idea of how to do this is to have the “false” part of my “ifelse” statement to basically tell the program to keep trying to assign the patch a different place if it has another patch touching any part of it, until all patches have a place with no other patches touching it all (including corners). I just have no idea if that is possible or what code could do that. Is there a netlogo primitive that is equivalent to "until" ? Any help or ideas would be appreciated!
Here is a part of my code:

```
patches-own [ quality ]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of number-of-patches patches 
  [ ifelse sum [ pcolor ] of neighbors = 0
    [ set quality random (2 + random 8)
      set pcolor scale-color green quality 0 10
    ]
    [ set pcolor black ; this is the line I need to change
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Please do not use a word processor to copy programming code, it does things like capitalise words and introduce blank lines. Also, when you attach tags to your question, please check the definition that you see to make sure the tag (like `patch') is being used in the way that you mean. I have cleaned up your question.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the primitives `while` and `neighbors` in the NetLogo dictionary. I am not completely clear on the sequencing you want in your code so I can't provide a full answer. However, you want something like:

```
 while any? neighbors [(however you define the ones you don't want to touch]
 [(try again)
 ]
```

Note that `patches` always touch other `patches` because the world is constructed as a grid of `patches`. So you presumably want `patches` with specific conditions (such as high values of quality) to not touch each other.

Answer (score 1):

As JenB says, patches are always touching other patches, so I'm assuming the question is "How can I generate *number-of-patches* green patches that aren't touching any other green patches?". Then I'd do this:

```
to setup-patches
  while [ count patches with [ shade-of? green pcolor ] < number-of-patches ]
  [ ask one-of patches with [ quality = 0 and count neighbors with [ shade-of? green pcolor ] = 0 ]
    [ set quality random (2 + random 8)
      set pcolor scale-color green quality 0 10 ] ]
end
```

Basically, *while* the number of green patches is less than the desired number of green patches, choose one of the patches that isn't green and doesn't have any green neighbors. Then turn it green.